# jq with select + awk

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, awk, jq, aws-cli

I'm trying to take a JSON array returned from AWS' cli and loop through each item and call another AWS command to get more details about the resource.  I'm open to another approach, this is how I'm approaching it right now.

I'm making a call to AWS to get the initial list and passing it into `jq` to be able to extract one property from each of the objects in the JSON list piping the output into `awk` to generate a new generate a new command to execute for each of the items in the first list.  I'm able to accomplish this with the following:

**Working without select**

```
aws acm list-certificates |
jq '.CertificateSummaryList[].CertificateArn' |
awk '{ c=system("aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn "$1 " | jq '''.Certificate.InUseBy,.Certificate.DomainName,.Certificate.CertificateArn'''"); }'
```

However I need to filter the response from each of those commands to only output the properties if a certain condition is valid and this is where I'm encountering an issue.  The updated command that I'm using:

**Failure when I add select**

```sh
aws acm list-certificates |
jq '.CertificateSummaryList[].CertificateArn' |
awk '{ c=system("aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn "$1 " | jq '''.Certificate |
select( .InUseBy != null)''' ");}'
```

Throws the following error:

```
no matches found: select( .InUseBy != null) "); }
awk: non-terminated string  | jq .Cer... at source line 1
 context is
     >>>  <<<
awk: giving up
 source line number 2
➜  ~
[1]    5484 done         aws acm list-certificates |
       5485 broken pipe  jq '.CertificateSummaryList[].CertificateArn' |
       5486 exit 2       awk
```

I've tried escaping the `|`, `(` and `)` without any success.  The command below is an example of a similar approach just short circuiting the first part and taking just one item from the list then doing the check to see if the length of one of the properties is greater than zero.

**Short-circuited to test the select portion**

```
aws acm list-certificates |
jq '.CertificateSummaryList[] | select (.CertificateArn=="arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:000000000000:certificate/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000").CertificateArn' |
xargs aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn |
jq '.Certificate | select( (.InUseBy | length) > 0) | .InUseBy, .Type'
```

So I'm pretty confident in the syntax of the second jq statement however I'm not sure what is causing the syntax error when I add the `select` portion to the statement.

---

[EDITED]

Sample `aws acm list-certificates` from [list-certificates — AWS CLI 1.18.117 Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/list-certificates.html#examples):

```
{
    "CertificateSummaryList": [
        {
            "CertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789012:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
            "DomainName": "www.example.com"
        },
        {
            "CertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:493619779192:certificate/87654321-4321-4321-4321-210987654321",
            "DomainName": "www.example.net"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using multiple escaping is a source of error, almost impossible to maintain, and prone to break anytime; when an in-between-generated outputs escapes and injects unattended syntax.

I'd recommend instead you either process the loop with bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r arn; do
  aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn "$arn" |
    jq '.Certificate | select( (.InUseBy | length) > 0) | .InUseBy, .Type'
done< <(
  aws acm list-certificates |
    jq -r '.CertificateSummaryList[].CertificateArn'
)
```

Or use `xargs` rather than a bash loop:

```sh
aws acm list-certificates |
  jq -r '.CertificateSummaryList[].CertificateArn' |
    xargs -l aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn |
      jq '.Certificate | select( (.InUseBy | length) > 0) | .InUseBy, .Type'
```